# VSCode markdown preview blank on launch from command line (code .)

Tags: visual-studio-code

1. Problem description: When launching /Docs folder containing markdown files using `code .` from the command line into VSCode, the files fail to render using markdown preview button. The previw window opens and is blank. When I open VSCode from windows menu, preview button works fine and renders all content for markdown files.
2. I have tried:

   - Problem is persistent across Windows 10 and Windows 11 OS.
   - If I open VSCode from file explorer or Windows menu, the markdown content renders using preview.
   - If I open VSCode using `code .`, the preview button fails to render markdown content and displays blank preview window.
   - If I launch from the command line using `code`, render also seems to fail.
3. Just looking for confirmation if this is a known issue? Would like to be able to launch from cmd and have markdown preview still work.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Thanks for the hint about launching from explorer though - at least I have a workaround now!

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you attempting to launch from an administrator command line? I've noticed that if I run `code .` from a normal one it works, but if I have to elevate to get administrator access it no longer works. When this occurs, the developer tools do not open either.

Comment: Yes, typically always run cmd as admin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found some more information so I'll make it an answer - this is a known issue in Visual Studio Code and is being tracked with:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122951

There are two work arounds:

1. Launch Visual Studio Code unelevated
2. Use the `--no-sandbox` argument